# Projection property of axes in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to run matlab code in octave which works quite well, but when it comes to the point:

```
axes('Projection','perspective')
```

the code breaks with following error

```
error: invalid value = perspective
error: set: invalid value for radio property "projection" (value = perspective)
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/plot/axes.m at line 39, column 9
```

I know from the [docs](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) that matlab supports this property, but octave seems not to support this feature. Do you know if I've to install an additional package to get this feature or does octave not support this feature at all?

The [octave doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axes-Properties.html) is not very helpful in this point. Additionally I didn't found any information on this.

Here is my list of installed packages (os = xubuntu 13.10 64 bit):

- i   liboctave-dev                   - Development files for the GNU Octave langu
- i A liboctave1                      - Shared libraries of the GNU Octave languag
- i   octave                          - GNU Octave language for numerical computat
- i A octave-common                   - architecture-independent files for octave
- i A octave-control                  - control functions for Octave from Octave-F
- i   octave-doc                      - PDF documentation on the GNU Octave langua
- i A octave-general                  - provide extra general functions for Octave
- i   octave-htmldoc                  - HTML documentation on the GNU Octave langu
- i   octave-image                    - image manipulation for Octave
- i A octave-info                     - GNU Info documentation on the GNU Octave l
- i A octave-io                       - input/output data functions for Octave
- i A octave-java                     - Java objects manipulation interface for Oc
- i   octave-linear-algebra           - additional linear-algebra functions for Oc
- i   octave-plot                     - additional plotting tools for Octave
- i   octave-plplot                   - Octave support for PLplot, a plotting libr
- i   octave-signal                   - signal processing functions for Octave
- i A octave-specfun                  - special mathematical functions for Octave
- i   octave-statistics               - additional statistical functions for Octav
- i   qtoctave                        - Qt front-end to Octave

Comment: With Octave 3.8.0, that property hasn't been implemented yet. No package will fix that. Fortunately, Octave is free software which means you're free to implement it.

Comment: Well, actually in Octave 3.8 the proper spelling for what you want is *perpective* (sic!), but it doesn't work anyway ;D

Comment: Do octave know that this is misspelled? Surely they wouldn't purposely use `perpective`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error on my octave version 3.8.2

the command

```
axes('Projection','perspective')
```

does not throw an error, however, as in other instances octave normally complains about single use quotations so you can try

```
axes("Projection","perspective")
```

According to the Octave [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Axes-Properties.html):

> projection: {"orthographic"} | "perspective"   selected: {"off"} |
>   "on"  selectionhighlight: "off" | {"on"}   tag: string, def. ""
>
> A user-defined string to label the graphics object.